# Update the node size of a digital ocean kubernetes cluster without replacing the whole cluster

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, digital-ocean

I successfully maintain a kubernetes cluster in digital ocean throught terraform. The core cluster configuration is the following:

```
resource "digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster" "cluster" {
  name     = var.name
  region   = var.region
  version  = var.k8s_version
  vpc_uuid = digitalocean_vpc.network.id

  node_pool {
    name       = "workers"
    size       = var.k8s_worker_size
    node_count = var.k8s_worker_count
  }
}
```

The problem is, I now need to increase the node size (stored in the variable `k8s_worker_size`).

If I simply change the variable to a new string, the terraform plan results in a full replace of the kubernetes cluster:

```
digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.cluster must be replaced
```

This is not doable in our production environment.

The correct procedure to perform this operation inside digital ocean is to:

- Create a new node pool, with the required size
- Use `kubectl drain` to remove our pods from the 'old' nodes
- Remove the previous node pool.

Of course, by doing this manually inside the digital ocean console, the terraform state is completely out-of-sync and is therefore unusable.

Is there a way to perform that operation through terraform?

As an alternative options, is it possible to "manually" update the terraform state in order to sync it with the real cluster state after I perform the migration manually?

Comment: This sounds like something best asked on the provider project. Looking at https://github.com/digitalocean/terraform-provider-digitalocean/pull/169 it looks like it was initially intended for the node pool size to be upgraded in place by creating a new node pool and attaching it but https://github.com/scotchneat/terraform-provider-digitalocean/commit/042e60ff6b8d633ef60ffda8faf529e590b52bb3 removed that without explaining why (it might not have worked) and the PR doesn't give any more context either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to perform that operation through terraform?

There might be some edge cases where there is a solution to this. Since I am not familiar with kubernetes inside DigitalOcean I can't share a specific solution.

> As an alternative options, is it possible to "manually" update the terraform state in order to sync it with the real cluster state after I perform the migration manually?

Yes! Do as you proposed manually and then remove the out-of-sync cluster with

```
terraform state rm digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.cluster
```

from the state. Please visit the corresponding [documentation for state rm](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/state/rm.html) and update the address if your cluster is in a module etc. Then use

```
terraform import digitalocean_kubernetes_cluster.cluster <id of your cluster>
```

to reimport the cluster. Please consult the [documentation for importing the cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#import) for the details. The documentations mentions something around tagging the default node pool.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I missed the `import` command when documenting about terraform. I will try it as soon as possible